# Working with Azure Blob Storage , to copy url data to blob?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

> The method startCopy(URL) is undefined for the type CloudBlockBlob

Getting the above Error while compiling the below code-

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;

public class CopyFromURLToBlob {
    public static final String storageConnectionString = "xyz" ; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = String.format(storageConnectionString);
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference("dbpcontent");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("directcopytoblobfromUrl.txt");

        String url = "http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/dbpedia_2016-10.owl";
        blob.startCopy(new URL(url));
        }}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `new URI(url)` instead of `new URL(url)`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Using 'new URI(url)' also giving same error

Comment: Which version of Azure Storage SDK are you using?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am new to it ,sorry for this question.. please help me with steps to check version..

Comment: Even I am new to this :). Unfortunately I don't use Java.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am writing code in my local eclipse and giving Azure Storage configuration .. earlier I was able to upload file from my local to Azure storage using JAVA.. but in this code I am getting this only error

Comment: @anshul What version of Azure Storage SDK for Java you used?